# How to inialize variable with small non-negative random numbers in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

How to inialize variable with small non-negative random numbers in tensorflow?

How to find all possible variable initializers, defined in TF in documentation?

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please mark it as correct so that people know what worked when they come across your question in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Create a variable and choose the random distribution of correct dimensions.

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((dim1, dim2)))
```

For initialization, you need to create random numbers. This link gives you all the random operations (distributions) in Tensorflow.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/constant_op#Random_Tensors

Answer (score 3):

Initializing variables with small non-negative numbers:

```
norm = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=0,  maxval = 1, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.variable_scope('scope') as scope:
     w = tf.get_variable('w', [inp.get_shape()[1], output_dim], initializer=norm, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: How is this non-negative ? The normal distribution has mean 0, and can take negative values

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options for non-negative [random numbers in TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/constant_op#Random_Tensors). As others have mentioned already, you can use [`tf.random_uniform`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform):

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, minval=0, maxval=max))
```

for uniform random numbers in `[minval, maxval)`. For more general distributions, you can use [`tf.random_gamma`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_gamma), which draws samples from a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) parameterized by a shape parameter `alpha`, and an inverse scale parameter `beta`. `alpha` has to be provided, but `beta=1` by default (even though the fingerprint says `None`):

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_gamma(shape, alpha=alpha, beta=beta))
```

The gamma distribution has support `[0, +inf)` and some other nice properties (maximum entropy distribution under some assumptions, conjugate prior for some things in Bayes statistics). You can get a lot of different shapes out of it depending on your parameters. It is kind of analogous to the normal distribution, but for positive numbers only.

You could also (although I don't know that I would recommend it; it feels weird) use [`tf.truncated_random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal), which samples from a normal distribution with specified `mean` and `stddev`, except that samples outside of plus-or-minus 2 standard deviations are dropped and resampled:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_random_normal(shape, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
```

where `mean` would be some positive value, and `stddev` would be *at most* equal to `mean/2`.